# Is there a way to provide a config file or private key to an Elastic Beanstalk instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, elastic-beanstalk

I have an EBS instance running a Golang webserver application, which uses a config.json that contains important and private configuration values like Database address, user and password.

I've been trying to find a solution to provide this configuration file to the EBS instance without needing to commit the file itself to version control (it's Github, by the way) but I haven't found anything useful.

Perhaps, there's no way of doing it without committing?