# How to set an application-specific configuration file in Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elastic-beanstalk

I have an application which I host in Elastic Beanstalk.

I have modified this application so that it can be configured with an external configuration file, but now I don't know how to upload/set the file in my Elastic Beanstalk environment. Ideally I would want to specify the file in the configuration of the environment, so that I can change the file without redeploying, and also redeploy without changing the file. If new instances are created, the file would be propagated to all of them.

So essentially, from my perspective it would be similar to setting and environment variable, except instead of a single value, I would provide a file, or a path to a file that I would somehow upload.

Is there a way to do this? If not, what would be the EB way of solving my situation?

This is an almost duplicate of [this other question](https://serverfault.com/questions/998318/is-there-a-way-to-provide-a-config-file-or-private-key-to-an-elastic-beanstalk-i), except that in that question, I believe the answer would be to set the secrets as environment variables. In my case, the nature of the configuration makes this not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usual workarounds:

1. Environment variables
2. Files on shared storage like EFS, S3
3. Push configuration changes via API

Second one is your option

Comment: I was hoping for a simpler solution - separately configured file storage seems like overkill for a configuration file - but I guess there's no such solution, sadly.